# Passing ID from json to controller with codeigniter CURL

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, curl

Hello i new on codeigniter, and i have problem when i develop my first website

I have an API, here my url API example

API SHOW ALL ARTICLES

```
http://localhost/vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles
```

API DETAIL ARTICLES

```
http://localhost/vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles?id_news=13
```

that API is show articles data with id_news is equal 13

I want show the detail articles with that API , and fill the parameter id_news dynamically when i click button in my website.

here my button code:

```
 <a href="<?= base_url().'admin/Articles/detail/'.$row->id_news ?>">
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Detail"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                            </a>
```

i tried many times,but i don't know to passing id_news to the controller,
here my controller code :

```
public function detail()
{
    $data['master'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get('http://localhost/vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles')); 
    $data['datanews'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get('http://localhost/vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles?id_news='.$data['master']['id_news']));

    $this->load->view('admin/articles_detail',$data);
}
```

i got an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: id_news

Filename: admin/Articles.php

Line Number: 106

Backtrace:

File: D:\RIFQI_FILE\xampp\htdocs\vectorkey\oneportal\application\controllers\admin\Articles.php
Line: 106
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\RIFQI_FILE\xampp\htdocs\vectorkey\oneportal\index.php
Line: 304
Function: require_once
```

Comment: what actually comes in $data['master'] ?

Comment: all data articles

Comment: add sample value here

Comment: the values is

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_news] => 13 [title] => TITLE [content] => CONTENT ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id_news] => 8 [title] => TITLE [content] => CONTENT ) )

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Get array values with index 0, like $arr[0]->id_news.

```
    public function detail()
    {
        $arr = $data['master'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get('http://localhost/vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles')); 
        $data['datanews'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get('http://localhost/vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles?id_news='.$arr[0]->id_news));

        $this->load->view('admin/articles_detail',$data);
    }
```

Comment: above you gave multiple master datas in array, which array index value of "id_news" have to pass?

Comment: i want the parameter dynamically fill id_news when i click button

example : 
when i click button articles with id_news = 10 , the go to the detail page articles with id_news = 10

Comment: see above your array result has many index, on which basis have to get the values of "id_news". if you want 1st index value will be like arr[0]->id_news or 2nd index arr[1]->id_news

Comment: in "vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles" file did get the values by $_GET[], ?

Comment: and try with static id_news values like "http://localhost/vectorkey/oneportalbackend/api/articles?id_news=10"